# Bootstrap Datatables Javascript - Lengthmenu and export buttons too smooshed against each other - want to create line break between the two

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a searchable table I'm developing where users need to be able to export their results, but also select the number of results they see.  The problem is that everything looks too crammed together.  I want to be able to add a line break, paragraph, or a div to space things out.  Basically, I want this:

**Project Search**

Show [Number] Entries

[Copy] [Excel] [CSV] [PDF] [Column Visibility]

[My table]

How would I go about doing this? I can't rely on my trusty BR and P html tags here, but I would like to figure this out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false
      },
      {
        "targets": [],
        "visible": false
      }
    ],

    buttons: [{
        extend: 'copyHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
              var text = node.textContent;
              return column === 10 ? text.replace(/Open$/, '').trim() : data;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
              var text = node.textContent;
              return column === 10 ? text.replace(/Open$/, '').trim() : data;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'csvHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
              var text = node.textContent;
              return column === 10 ? text.replace(/Open$/, '').trim() : data;
            }
          }
        }
      },


      {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        orientation: 'landscape',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
              var text = node.textContent;
              return column === 10 ? text.replace(/Open$/, '').trim() : data;
            }
          }
        }
      },

      'colvis'
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
div.dt-button-collection {
  width: 215px;
}

.display.dataTable {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.modal {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

td.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel "=stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The known name of the project.">Project Name</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The provided unique ID that distinguishes projects.">Project Number</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The conclusing time point of a project, which is sometimes, but not always the point at which funding ends.">End Date</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The primary funder of the project.">Funder</th>

      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="A brief description on the scope and aims of a project.">Abstract</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td>Project 1</td>

      <td>P-1</td>

      <td>2018-04-30 00:00:00</td>

      <td>NIH</td>

      <td>
        <div id="ex83" class="modal">
          <p>

            Abstract 1
            <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#ex83" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Project 2</td>

      <td>P-2</td>

      <td>2024-03-31 00:00:00</td>

      <td>NIH</td>

      <td>
        <div id="ex103" class="modal">
          <p>

            Abstract 2
            <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#ex103" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Project 3</td>

      <td>P-3</td>

      <td>2021-01-31 00:00:00</td>

      <td>NIH</td>

      <td>
        <div id="ex111" class="modal">
          <p> Abstract 3</p>
          <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#ex111" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code does exactly what you want. Run the snippet. It likely wasn't working for you because [your code is a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63488801/revisions). You had a closing `</div>` tag instead of a closing `</head>` tag. There was no starting `<body>` tag. You have a separate `<style>` tag for every style rule. **Format your code.** Nasty code begets bugs. Cleanliness is next to godliness.

Comment: Ideally, everyone would have clean code with minimal fluff and no unnecessary tags.  Unfortunately, that takes experience, of which I have little.  I'm trying to learn and I've found Stack to be a great resource.  With that said, I appreciate your revisions and I ran them in the snippet, however the same crammed problem remained once I maximized it to full screen. Update: I realize you probably just edited my code for clarity, not to resolve the issue.  All good.

Comment: Take a look at the DataTables [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option - it includes syntax which allows you to add spaces around the different DataTables DOM sections (buttons, pagination, etc). There are some examples on that documentation page which include clearing elements.  The end result can be a bit cryptic, but it does what you need here.

Comment: Thank you.  I took a look and I was able to move things pretty comfortable, but I am still struggling to keep length changing input control on top of my buttons.  I looked for a few examples and couldn't find any.  Any help is appreciated.  Thankfully, this is the last piece of this project and then I'll be done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, I only added this CSS rule:

```
.dataTables_length {
    position: relative;
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Obviously, if you don't want the `Show [Number] Entries` horizontally centered, just remove `text-align: center;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    dom: '<l>Bfrtip',
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false
      },
      {
        "targets": [],
        "visible": false
      }
    ],

    buttons: [{
        extend: 'copyHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
              var text = node.textContent;
              return column === 10 ? text.replace(/Open$/, '').trim() : data;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
              var text = node.textContent;
              return column === 10 ? text.replace(/Open$/, '').trim() : data;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'csvHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
              var text = node.textContent;
              return column === 10 ? text.replace(/Open$/, '').trim() : data;
            }
          }
        }
      },


      {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        orientation: 'landscape',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: ':visible',
          format: {
            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
              var text = node.textContent;
              return column === 10 ? text.replace(/Open$/, '').trim() : data;
            }
          }
        }
      },

      'colvis'
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
div.dt-button-collection {
  width: 215px;
}

.display.dataTable {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.modal {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

td.none {
  display: none;
}

div.dt-buttons {
    float: none;
}

.dataTables_length {
    position: relative;
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel "=stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The known name of the project.">Project Name</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The provided unique ID that distinguishes projects.">Project Number</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The conclusing time point of a project, which is sometimes, but not always the point at which funding ends.">End Date</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The primary funder of the project.">Funder</th>

      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="A brief description on the scope and aims of a project.">Abstract</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td>Project 1</td>

      <td>P-1</td>

      <td>2018-04-30 00:00:00</td>

      <td>NIH</td>

      <td>
        <div id="ex83" class="modal">
          <p>

            Abstract 1
            <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#ex83" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Project 2</td>

      <td>P-2</td>

      <td>2024-03-31 00:00:00</td>

      <td>NIH</td>

      <td>
        <div id="ex103" class="modal">
          <p>

            Abstract 2
            <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#ex103" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Project 3</td>

      <td>P-3</td>

      <td>2021-01-31 00:00:00</td>

      <td>NIH</td>

      <td>
        <div id="ex111" class="modal">
          <p> Abstract 3</p>
          <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#ex111" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

By the way, you didn't say anything about the `Search box`